# Electric motor torque

Tags: motor

How to know if the required torque is input or output?

[image]

Source:

PPI PE Power Practice Problems, 4th Edition – More Than 400 Practice Problems for the NCEES PE Electrical Power Exam

by John A. Camara PE

PPI, a Kaplan Company; Revised, Fourth Edition, Revised (March 10, 2021)

ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1591267862

ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1591267867

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Do you think you can elaborate on your question a bit?

Comment: Is it as output or input?

Comment: It's an electric motor. Therefore it has an electrical (volts and amps) input, and a mechanical (speed and torque) output. A generator would have a mechnical input and an electrical output. A load being driven by a motor would have a mechancial (speed and torque) input, and an outptu depending on the type of load.

Comment: Why does it matter?  That motor can deal with its design torque, whether operating in the motoring region, or (on a drive) regenerative region (provided the energy can be dissipated).

Comment: @RDrast this is not perfectly true. An induction motor operated as a generator may not be great for generating. It can operate in regen, of course, but may need to be de-rated. Induction generators will be designed specifically for the generation case and will have no problem.

Comment: @RDrast https://acim.nidec.com/motors/usmotors/TechDocs/ProFacts/Induction-Generator

Answer (score 0):

In electric motor problems, "developed torque" often means the "electrical torque" or the torque produced by the rotor. The motor's "output torque" is the torque delivered to the load. Output torque is developed torque minus mechanical losses which consist of friction and aerodynamic drag (windage).

Electric generator problems are similar but the driving torque is equal to the torque driving the rotor plus the mechanical losses.

You sometimes must make an assumption about which torque is required based on the problem wording and the information available. If you make an assumption in working a problem, be sure to clearly state what you have assumed and why.